# Adding a rich text description to blog properties in the Orchard CMS

Tags: richtextbox, blogs, orchardcms

I'm setting up a site on Orchard CMS and I want to put links into the description of each blog. Currently it just has a space for text in the Description but I need rich text. Can I add a rich text part to the Blog content type or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the Body part to the blog content type, set-up placement for it and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try overriding the view that outputs the description to the front end to use `@Html.Raw(Model.Description)`, and just type in some HTML into the description field. I'm not sure if it will accept the HTML tags in the editor without modifications though.

Actually, if the above doesn't work, adding a body part should, and then override the display template to display the description from the body part.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, I don't have enough reputation, FWIW in Orchard 1.8 (current) you only need to edit the content definition for type 'blog' to add the 'Body' part, the default placement already has it.